# Using Compass (sass) features without compass project

Tags: sass, compass-sass

My problem: I want to use some compass features (mostly sprites generation and css3 mixins), but I don't want to create a compass project for it. My project structure should be a bit more complicated than compass allows me to create. So I'd like to stay in my project with sass, but import and use some compass features in it. Is it possible?

Comment: Would you be so kind to share more info about your project organization and which environment you use?

Comment: I'd like to keep partials very small, something like blocks description, so there will be a lot of them. It would be nice to have a folder for each block with .scss, .js and images inside. Otherwise there will be a great mess with hundreds of files. But I can't make compass to use partials from subfolders.

Comment: Compass doesn't care where you stuff your partials, it only cares where the Sass files it needs to compile live.  The images only need to live within the configured images directory if you're using the image helper functions on them.

Comment: @cimmanon, Well, I have folder named "sass" (configured in config.rb), inside it I have folder named, for example, "header", and inside this folder there is _header.scss file. And when I try to import header partial to screen.scss, neither import "header", nor import "header/_header" works. I also tried with extension — no way. If I could add all subfolders to include search path it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compass IS able to manage all your stuff. Just give it a try.

Here's an example, this is the structure of a Compass project i'm currently working on:

[image]

First of all, you should have a folder like `sass` where you store your non-partial SASS files, e. g. `sass/style.sass` or `sass/screen.scss`. Your `config.rb` should point at it.

Then create a subfolder called `partials` where you store all the stuff.

In `partials` subfolder you start creating the structure:

```
sass/
  partials/
    _global.sass
    _modules.sass
  style.sass
```

The contents of your `style.sass` should be like this:

```
@import partials/global
@import partials/modules
```

This structure is easily extendable. Once your partial grows large and you decide to split it, just create a subfolder named after the partial, create smaller partials there and import them from the initial partial:

```
sass/
  partials/
    global/
      _extendables.sass
      _functions.sass
      _mixins.sass
      _variables.sass
    _global.sass
    _modules.sass
  style.sass
```

Contents of `_global.sass`:

```
@import global/extendables
@import global/functions
@import global/mixins
@import global/variables
```

This makes your project structure easily extendable.

Note that if you're using the SCSS syntax, quotes are necessary in the import statements, e. g. `@import "global/extendables";`.

If the imports aren't working for you, please share your project structure, the exact code you use and the error text you receive.

Comment: Now it seems to work. I see, the folder with partials should be named partials? Can it be configured to another name? I found absolutely nothing about that in configuration reference.

Comment: Folder names can be whatever you want. Naming folders after partials is just a very convenient way to grow your codebase large.

Comment: @lomaus Well, thanks, maybe I did something wrong, but I could't make it work until I named the folder "partials". Now folder name doesn't matter, looks like some kind of my mistake. Have no idea what was wrong, but now any folder structure works well, even if all subfolders are just inside saas. Thanks. Hope I'll never meet such a strange behavior again.